# EJB3 interceptor cannot bootstrap context

Tags: spring, dependencies, ejb-3.0, code-injection

I'm trying to inject Spring beans into an EJB using 
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)

Here's my EJB:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class processMethodService implements
    processMethodService {

    @Autowired
    private SomeBean bean;

    @Schedule(minute = "*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void startProcessing() {
        //businesslogic 
    }
}
```

And beanRefContext.xml as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="ejb-businesslayer.application.context" lazy-init="true"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/META-INF/spring-config.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean> `
```

beanRefContext.xml,spring-config.xml are under META-INF folder.

when startProcessing is called for every 5 minutes and  we are getting the below exception

```
Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: session bean lifecycle interceptor failure;nested exception is:org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return  specified  BeanFactory instance: factory key [null], 
from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory] is defined
```

Please find the complete exception as below

```
Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: session bean lifecycle interceptor failure;nested exception is: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException:  Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [null], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory] is defined`enter code here`
at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:466)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.SessionBeanO.callLifecycleInterceptors(SessionBeanO.java:288)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:399)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1238)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1356)
at  com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate(UncachedActivationStrategy.java:88)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.preInvokeActivateBean(Activator.java:615)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:4205)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3535)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimedObjectWrapper.invokeCallback(TimedObjectWrapper.java:110)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpListener.doWork(TimerNpListener.java:293)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpListener.doWorkWithRetries(TimerNpListener.java:171)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpListener.fired(TimerNpListener.java:141)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.callListenerMethod(AlarmImpl.java:427)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:228)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1178)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(AlarmImpl.java:249)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:333)
at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:230)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [null], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:402)
at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.getBeanFactoryReference(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:160)
at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:141)
at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.doAutowireBean(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:121)
at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doLifeCycle(InvocationContextImpl.java:273)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.SessionBeanO.callLifecycleInterceptors(SessionBeanO.java:274)
```

Please guide me on  how to resolve this error

Comment: Anyone has a solutions to this?

Comment: Ping. Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator is looking for resource classpath*:beanRefContext.xml, so the beanRefContext.xml file has to be in the classpath, ref [this link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/ejb/45663-ejb3-interceptor-cannot-bootstrap-context),

Move `beanRefContext.xml` into a folder that's in the class path and that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think removing META-INF should help. Also, I just solved this same issue by moving context in question to /resources directory